# Make sns.swarmplot with respect to two categorical variables in x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, swarmplot

I have a pandas DataFrame and, I could make a sex-age swarm plot (picture have two columns male and female). and also diabetes-age swarm plot (two columns yes and no)

How could I make a swarm plot with four columns:

male&yes male&no female&yes female&no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `hue` parameter of `sbn.swarmplot`:

```
g = sbn.swarmplot(x="Gender", y="Age", hue="Diabetes", data=data, dodge=True, size=10)
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What if we I had three categories? (and so we want eight columns) @Michael

Comment: Then you can start using `sbn.catplot`. This allows you to further use row- and column-stratification to split between categories.